# Using bootstrap-select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf, twitter-bootstrap

I am supposed to use [bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) to give a user a choice of titles e.g. Mr, Mrs or Ms.

Here's the select HTML:

```
<select name="adultSelect" class="selectpicker adultTitle_">
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Mrs</option>
    <option value="3">Ms</option>
</select>
```

I want to assign the value to a variable in the backing bean when the user clicks the
form's submit button. For example, here's how I do the user's surname:

```
<div>
    <h:inputText value ="#{bean.surname}" label="Surname"></h:inputText>
</div>
```

From what I can see, the `<select>` tag doesn't have a `value` attribute available to it.

The JS I have for the selectpicker looks like this:

```
$(".selectpicker").selectpicker({
    style: "btn",
    size: 3
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand your problem.. What's your problem the plugin or ??

Comment: @DrixsonOseña My problem is, I think, that I am not using a JSF element. Will update when I'm sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your using JSF, in this case it would require the use of `h:selectOneMenu`:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.adultSelect}" styleClass="selectpicker adultTitle_">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Mr" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Mrs" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Ms" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The above is psuedo code since I'm not aware of the name of property holding the value for the field represented by the dropdown. The `value` attribute of the select tag must be mapped to the bean property, so replace `#{bean.adultSelect}` with the appropriate field.

Comment: Yes, I'm using JSF, and I was using selectOneMenu elements, but I've been told they want me to use the bootstrap-select plugin, hence this question. **EDIT** nevermind, I see you used the selectpicker style. I'll try this! Thanks!

Comment: @Skytiger Hope this helps. Eventually that JSF is going to be turned into HTML.  If the appropriate classes are on the element, the bootstrap styling should pickup.